# reinterpret_cast for void* to char*[]

Tags: c++, c++11

My inside fields:

```
void*  argRows;
char* rows[] = reinterpret_cast<char[]*>(argRows);
```

Can I resolve like as methoding?

Comment: Has anyone really been far even as decided to use even go want to do look more like?

Comment: Potato fields sheep like kites

Comment: Okay thx , I to try here `char** rows = reinterpret_cast<char**>(argRows);`

Comment: `Twas brilig, and the slithy toves did gyre and gimble in the wabe;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what "methoding" means, but that code is not valid.

You can't initialize an array from a pointer.

> Okay thx , I to try here `char** rows = reinterpret_cast<char**>(argRows);`

Yes, that's OK (assuming `argRows` really does have a compatible type, if it doesn't you can do the cast but you can't use `rows` safely).